# Desktop Application - Update Text to website

Tags: c#, .net

We have a 5 page website and we are looking to make a desktop application to update parts of the text just 1 or 2 words to start off with , simple change the html word of hello to test from the desktop program.

I know parts of visual basic 2008 but im not a master of it and so i didn't know if that was the best way to go forward or any other programming languages.

Also what would be the best code way to try and update the text on the website

Any websites would be appreciated so i could learn and possibly build on this as this would be something id like to get into

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bit much to answer fully here.  I can give you the basic steps and links to resources to help you on your way.

Without going into specifics, you want to do the following:

- Create your website using ASP.NET (since you tagged this as .NET)
- Save the text that you want to be changeable in a database
- Use DataBinding in ASP.NET to retrieve the data from the database to show it on the pages.

  - there are plenty of videos on how to do this at http://www.asp.net
  - You'll have to choose between Web Forms and MVC.  if you're brand new I won't try to confuse you.  WebForms is a bit easier to use if you've never done real web programming before, but MVC is becoming much more popular.  Since it sounds like you're new I'm going to recommend you start at http://www.asp.net/web-forms and pay attention to the "Learning Resources" area
- Create a Windows Forms application to update the data

  - there are plenty of videos on how to do this at http://www.windowsclient.net
  - Technically you could update the data from an ASP.NET application, or even a Visual Studio Lightswitch app, but you specified you wanted to make a Desktop app, which I interperet as being a standard Windows app.

Of course, you'll have to host this website in IIS.  I'm assuming you're already doing that...